# Descomprimir un archivo mediante la consola de windows en R

Tags: r, cmd, shell

Tengo el siguiente problema, todos los días debo descomprimir un archivo con un nombre variable en el tiempo y por ende quiero automatizar ese proceso, el formato del archivo es .rar, si fuese .zip, conozco varios métodos rápidos para descomprimirlo mediante R pero ese no es el caso.

Es por ello que recurro a descomprimirlo mediante la consola de windows utilizando R. Cuando quiero utilizar un comando cmd, utilizo las funciones shell(), system() o bien la Terminal, ademas tengo Winrar como variable de entorno en mi sesion de windows, por lo cual puedo hacer uso de esta solo usando 'UnRaR' en la consola.

Ejemplo de mis archivos:

```
nombre_archivo = paste0(gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()), "_archivo.rar") # archivo con nombre distinto cada día

entrada = paste0("D:/Bastian/",nombre_archivo) # directorio del archivo comprimido
salida  = "D:/Bastian/" # lugar donde descomprimirlo
cmd_1   = "UnRaR x"  # comando a usar para descomprimir
```

Finalmente lo que logre como solución parche es lo siguiente:

```
shell('UnRaR x "D:/Bastian/20211104_archivo.rar" "D:/Bastian/"')
```

Me funciona pero debo modificar la fecha a mano y no es eficiente, existe alguna manera de hacer?

```
shell(paste(cmd_1, entrada, salida))
```

y que no me tire un error, ya que las comillas me juegan en contra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el problema pasa por la necesidad de incorporar comillas dobles en el comando, puedes "escaparlas" mediante la contrabarra: `\"`, es decir, algo así:

```
entrada = paste0("\"D:/Bastian/",nombre_archivo, "\"")
salida  = "\"D:/Bastian/\""
```

o incluso, si usas comillas simples para encerrar la cadena puedes incorporar las dobles sin problema:

```
entrada = paste0('"D:/Bastian/',nombre_archivo, '"')
salida  = '"D:/Bastian/"'
```

Comment: Pero aun asi no logro llegar a la estructura ('string "string" "string"'), ya que con lo que me dices solo logro escapar las comillas dobles

Comment: @BastianAndres, tal vez te interpreté mal, con el código de mi respuesta puedo hacer: `cat(paste(cmd_1, entrada, salida))` y la cadena final a ejecutar sería: `UnRaR x "D:/Bastian/20211105_archivo.rar" "D:/Bastian/"`

Comment: exactamente a eso queria llegar, necesito aplicar eso con comillas simples a la funcion shell, como podria hacerlo ? shell('UnRaR x "D:/Bastian/20211105_archivo.rar" "D:/Bastian/"'), ya que el cat es como un print

Comment: ¿Y que pasa si haces `shell(paste(cmd_1, entrada, salida))` con el ejemplo que te dí?

Comment: Me funciono con lo que dijiste: shell(paste(cmd_1, entrada, salida)) usando el metodo para escaparlas, muchas gracias patricio